# Making Java window without JFrame or AWT

Tags: java, swing, window, awt

First of all, I want you to know that I searched the web for that but couldn't find anything.
I remember that I saw a thread on it once but couldn't find it again; it was a long time ago.

I want to know how to make my own window, without JFrame or AWT.
Everywhere I am searching just shows me library and pre-made code but I can't learn how it works inside.
I want to know how to build a window, without what Java already gave me.

The good thing and the bad thing in Java is that Java makes things easy for the developers,
so, that's why I tried C, searched for assembly code and tried to find a way to do this, but all of the approaches used libraries.

That why, I want to know, it is even possible?
Don't need all of the windows, just the base of it or even pixels on the screen, but something that will not include using more libraries or made classes that were built for that and everyone using just because this is the only thing they know.

Thanks to everyone that will help me and will answer my question(s) :)

Comment: Java is reliant on the availability of functionality which is derived from multiple different operating systems, the available AWT, Swing and JavaFX frameworks abstract the complexities and differences that occur between operating systems into a usable package where the developer no longer needs to care about how the window is created, only that it operates in a specific manner. The ONLY solution you would have to create your own frame would be to resort to JNI/JNA. This would then raise the question of "how would you paint to this window?".

Comment: The question raises more questions. If you want to do this, the. Why use Java? Why not use the native libraries available at the os level using languages like C/Objective C/Swift which give you direct access to the system?  Unless ute going to write your operating system, you will always be operating through some api/library layer, that's kind of the point

Comment: @MadProgrammer even in c i saw only libraries and couldn't see a way without one. I don't mind settle and use another language, as long as i will understand what inside it and not use the class/library without knowing what i am doing

Comment: But that's my point, the window is provided by the operating system, which provides libraries for developers to create this functionality.  The OS manages the event notification/messaging process and provides a means by which the developer/window can actually paint.  Even if you wrote your operating system, you would be at the mercy of the hardware driver libraries...

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok, so i will use the OS library, but even then i see only simple code of creating window from your width, height and title. how can i "draw" my own window, without using one that already made for me?

Comment: Essentially, you don't.  You ask the OS for "window" "canvas", if should be able to get an undecorated window (which is just a big blank rectangle) and you should then be able to paint to it.  You might even be able to make the "window" transparent as well...

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok, this is the best i cant find, i will settle this. how can i do that? i guess that better then this i will no be able to find but it sounds quite good. i you could tell me what to search/give an examples it will be great. better if you will write is as an answer

Comment: Do you want to do it through Java or natively?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i prefer java but i will accept any language if it is not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, we are reliant on bindings into the native OS.  The reason we have abstract frameworks, like AWT, Swing, JavaFX, SWT is because the process by which this is done is not trivial, especially if you actually want to paint to these surfaces in some meaningful way and is compounded when you consider the different requirements of the available operating systems.

Depending on what you actually want to achieve, will depend on which way you will go, for example...

## You could...

Use a `JWindow` or an undecorated `JFrame`.  This provides you with a available painting surface and a connection into a ready made event queue (message loop).

These two windows present you with an "empty" rectangle with no decorations.  When dealing with these types of windows, you can provide your own decorations directly or via a custom look and feel.

## You could...

Use a JNI (native) binding directly into the operating system which would allow you to ask the OS to create a window of your own.  This means that you become responsible for determining how you are going to paint to the window, how you are going to process messages (events) from the OS that are targeted to your window and all other considerations.

Take a look at [JNA `Win32WindowDemo.java`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/native_window_msg/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Win32WindowDemo.java) or if you really want to get funky, you could also have a look at ...

- [JOGL (OpenGL bindings for Java](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/)
- [OpenGL bindings for Java](http://opengl.j3d.org/)
- [lwjgl (light weight Java Game library)](http://www.lwjgl.org/)
- [directx4j](https://code.google.com/p/directx4java/)
- [java-direct3d](http://java-direct3d.sourceforge.net/web/)

as some additional bindings into native graphics library

Answer (score -1):

you could just use message dialogue boxes. I know I made a program that ran entirely off of them.

This is a rock paper scissors program I made a while ago that  runs just off of option panes.

```
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AI 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int scan = 0;
    String bool = "";
    int rps;
    String type = "";
    int option;
    int counter = 0;
    String stuff = "";
    int cpu = 0;
    int foo = 0;
    int total = 0;
    while (true)
        {
        while(true)
        {



                type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose what game you would like to play. \n best of 3 \n best of 5 \n best of 7 \n first to 10");
                stuff = type.toLowerCase();
                if (stuff.equals ("best of 3"))
                {
                    option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play a best of 3 game?", "Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    break;
                }
                else if (stuff.equals ("best of 5"))
                {
                    option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play a best of 5 game?", "Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    break;
                }
                else if (stuff.equals ("best of 7"))
                {
                    option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play a best of 7 game?", "Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    break;
                }
                else if (stuff.equals ("first to 10"))
                {
                    option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play a game to 10?", "Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (stuff.equals("best of 3"))
                foo = 3;
            else if (stuff.equals("best of 5"))
                foo = 5;
            else if (stuff.equals("best of 7"))
                foo = 7;
            else if (stuff.equals("first to 10"))
                foo = 10;
            for (int i = 0; i <= foo; i++)
            {
            while(true)
            {
            scan = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter a number between 1 and 3. \n 1: rock\n 2: paper\n 3: scissors"));
            if (scan == 1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose rock.");
                    break;
                }
            else if (scan == 2)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose paper.");
                    break;
                }
            else if (scan == 3)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose scissors.");
                    break;
                }
            else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Choose a valid number");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        rps = generator.nextInt(3) + 1; 
        String str;
        if (rps == 1)
            {
            str = "The cpu chose rock!";
            }
        else if (rps == 2)
            {
            str = "The cpu chose paper!";
            }
        else 
            {
            str = "The cpu chose scissors!";
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,str);



            if (rps == 1 && scan == 2)
                {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you won!");
                counter++;
                total++;

                }
            else if (rps == 2 && scan == 3)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you won!");
                counter++;
                total++;

            }
            else if (rps == 3 && scan == 1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you won!");
                counter++;
                total++;

            }
            else if (rps == scan)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Try again!");
                continue;
            }
            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you lose!");
                cpu++;
                total++;

            }
            if(stuff.equals("best of 3") && counter == 2 || cpu ==2)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (stuff.equals("best of 5") && counter==3 || cpu == 3)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (stuff.equals("best of 7") && counter == 4 || cpu == 4)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (stuff.equals("first to 10") && counter == 10 || cpu ==10)
            {
                break;
            }

        }




            bool = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("do you want play another game? \n Type in yes or no");
            if (bool.equals("yes"))
                continue;
            else if (bool.equals("no"))
            break;

    }
    }
```

}

Comment: it is not what i ment, i want to create a windows and know what i am doiong, not to take classes that were given to me and use it without knowing what i am doing